Using Cypress 10+, how can I specify which .json data file to use for a test run from the CLI or node.js script?
I run my suite of Cypress tests on multiple domains, and with a different set of pre-written input data each time.
I load data from a .json file using a helper function like so:
//utils.js

const TEST_DATA_JSON = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_01.json')
// const TEST_DATA_JSON = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_02.json')
// const TEST_DATA_JSON = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_03.json')


export function getClientModeFromURL(baseUrl) {
  if (baseUrl.includes('client01')) {
    return 'CLIENT_01'
  } else if (baseUrl.includes('client02')) {
    return 'CLIENT_02'
  } else if (baseUrl.includes('client03')) {
    return 'CLIENT_03'
  } else if (baseUrl.includes('client04')) {
    return 'CLIENT_04'
  } else if (baseUrl.includes('client05')) {
    return 'CLIENT_05'
  }
  return 'CLIENT_01'; // Fall-back to client01 as these are the 'baseline' key-values.
}

export function getTestData(text) {
  const CLIENT_KEY = getClientModeFromURL(Cypress.config('baseUrl'))

  if (TEST_DATA_JSON[CLIENT_KEY] && TEST_DATA_JSON[CLIENT_KEY][text]) {
    return TEST_DATA_JSON[CLIENT_KEY][text]
  } else {
    return text
  }
}

And call the helper function within the Cypress test spec like so:
//example_spec.cy.js

import * as utils from './utils.js'

  it('Manage Primary Office', () => {
    cy.contains(utils.getTestData('primary_office_name'))
        .siblings()
        .contains('Manage')
        .click()
  })

Currently I manually switch between each testData_alt_xx.json file manually before each run; executing runs from the CLI with node.js:
npx cypress run --config baseUrl=https://test.client01.global/

Is there a way I can specify which .json file to use from the command line?
I've tried to use as global variable as the path to the data file:
//utils.js

const TEST_DATA_JSON_PATH = Cypress.env('TEST_DATA_JSON_PATH')
const TEST_DATA_JSON = require(TEST_DATA_JSON_PATH)

I store the testData_alt_xx.json files in the cypress/fixtures/ folder, and a  so I try to pass the global variable from the CLI:
npx cypress run --config baseUrl=https://test.client01.global/ --env TEST_DATA_JSON_PATH=cypress/fixtures/testData_alt_01.json

This results in an uncaught error:
  1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test:
     Error: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Cannot find module 'cypress/fixtures/testData_alt_01.json'

The file is in the expected location. Have I made a mistake in the syntax, or is there a broader problem with what I'm attempting to do?

You could specify the data version an environment variable to indicate which json file to use.
I don't think you can use a variable with require(some-varaible), so you would have to load them all if you want to use the utils code.
script
npx cypress run --env data=data1

test
const data1 = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_01.json')
const data2 = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_02.json')
const data3 = require('../fixtures/testData_alt_03.json')

let TEST_DATA;
switch (Cypress.env('data')) {
  case 'data1':
    TEST_DATA = data1
    break;
  case 'data2':
    TEST_DATA = data2
    break;
  case 'data3':
    TEST_DATA = data3
    break;
  default:
    TEST_DATA = data1
}


While that technically works, it causes loading unused files and besides is not really elegant.
In simple Cypress code, you can get a cleaner test
npx cypress run --env data=testData_alt_02.json

const dataFileToUse = Cypress.env('data')
cy.fixture(dataFileToUse).then(data => {
  cy.contains(data['primary_office_name'])
   ...


Thanks for the response @Wick.Welker. I used the first method you suggested and this works fine for what I'm currently trying to do. I appreciate the info on the more elegant solution too. This would require a major rewrite of everything I've got, and I'll consider this further when time allows.
